# FormatConditions border on a single edge

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a border between rows when the data in column 1 changes. This code breaks at `.LineStyle = xlContinuous`. The error I get is "Unable to set the LineStyle property of the Border class".

Is there an error in the code or an alternate way of doing this?

```
Sub AddBorders()
    With Range("A:B").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A1<>A2")
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that it is not `xlEdgeBottom` it is just `xlBottom`.  So change the line:

`With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)`

to

`With .Borders(xlBottom)`

and it worked for me

Comment: That is strange since Range.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) is what actually comes up in intellisense. This worked exactly how I wanted. Thanks you!

Comment: @Ripster Yeah I found this strange myself.  It looks like the this is not a `Range.Borders` its a property part of the `FormatCondition`.  Because yeah, `xlEdgeBottom` is what you use for `Range.Borders()`

Comment: OMG that is not intuitive at all.  But it works so thank you!  By the way, I had to cast mine (in C# anyway) to get it to work `.Borders[(Excel.XlBordersIndex)Excel.Constants.xlTop].Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `xlBottom` instead of `xlEdgeBottom`, another possible of cause of this error is having applied more than three conditional formats to the same range. I was having the same issue, and this is what resolved it for me.

The [MSDN documentation on the `Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822801%28v=office.15%29.aspx) states:

> You cannot define more than three conditional formats for a range. Use the Modify method to modify an existing conditional format, or use the Delete method to delete an existing format before adding a new one.