# Strange errors reading properties of a FormatCondition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `FormatCondition`, `cf1`. I do the following:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim fcs As FormatConditions
Dim cf1 As FormatCondition
Dim b1 As Border

Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set fcs = WS.Cells.FormatConditions
Set cf1 = fcs.item(1)
Set b1 = cf1.Borders.item(xlEdgeBottom)

Dim ls As XlLineStyle
ls = b1.LineStyle
```

If I then try to read the `b1.LineStyle` in the Immediate window or assign it to a variable (per the last line above) I get

> Error 1004: 'Unable to get the LineStyle property of the Border class'

(It's the same error string in the watch list but without the error number)

I get something similar for `b1.Weight`

This happens whether there is a line on the border of the Conditional Format or not, which surely cannot be right. If there is indeed no Line Style for that format I would think that `LineStyle` should then be `xlLineStyleNone`, and if there is a Line Style then surely it should be readable?

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?

Please note: I've looked at the borders found and some of the other Border properties seem right (ie the `Color=0` and `ColorIndex` is either `-4142` or `-4105`). `ThemeColor` and `TintAndShade` are `Null`, and `Creator` is `xlCreatorCode`.

I found some references to issues in **setting** LineStyle and Weight, and those said that the sheet was locked. This is not the case here as far as I know.

---

ADDITION:
I sometimes get a different error when trying to read `b1.ThemeColor` as well.

> 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

in the watch list, or

> Run-time error 5: 'Invalid procedure call or argument'

when reading in the Immediate window. Other times it is just `Null`

---

FURTHER ADDITION:
For `cf1.Interior.InvertIfNegative` I get

> 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

in the watch list, or

> Run-time error 1004: 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

when trying to read in the Immediate window.

There may be others I haven't found yet.

Comment: Can you provide more code please? How is `cf1` defined and initialized? Can you provide a [mcve] to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - Done, sorry. I've checked, and the FormatCondition certainly seems to be valid, it holds values that I would expect in most of the properties. You will need to create an excel sheet with an appropriate Conditional Formatting rule to test.

Comment: The rules I am using are using a formula, eg `=NOT(ISNUMBER(C9))`, and impose a cell fill colour and sometimes a border on the bottom of the cell, and cover a range of cells, eg `$C$8:$C$39`

Comment: Use the DisplayFormat of the Cell instead of going through the formatconditions

Comment: Thanks @EvR but I actually need the FormatConditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I can reproduce the issue you describe.

The issue seems to be in `Set b1 = cf1.Borders.item(xlEdgeBottom)` which is correct according to the documentation [FormatCondition.Borders property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.borders).

But there seems to be a bug, because the value of `xlEdgeBottom` is `9` (according to [xlBordersIndex enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex)) and if we have a look into the debug of `cf1.Borders` we see that there is only item 1 … 4 (see image) where 4 seems to be the bottom border.

[image]

If no one else has a very good idea here I would say this looks like a Excel bug.

To workaround this you can use eg `Set b1 = cf1.Borders.item(4)` for the bottom border.

---

#### So the solution is …

that `Set b1 = cf1.Borders.item(xlBottom)` actually worked for me.

Obviously the  `FormatCondition.Borders` doesn't use the correct [xlBordersIndex enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex) as it should do but instead uses `xlTop`, `xlLeft`, `xlBottom`, `xlRight`.

Also refer to [FormatConditions border on a single edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797776/formatconditions-border-on-a-single-edge).

But still this is not in accordance with the documentation and must be a bug.

Comment: Honestly, I'd been wondering vaguely about that (as I checked the `cf1.Borders.Count` value somewhere else) but figured that Excel must just make it work somehow, perhaps by the valid items in the collection starting at an index of 5, or something - I'm not as familiar with the nitty gritty of VBA as I am of c#, and since I could see that at least some of the properties of the Border seemed valid, it never occurred to me that the overall Border might not be.

Comment: I should mention, if only for others who read this under different circumstances, that it might conceivably only be like this for Borders on Conditional Formatting... normal Borders on a Range might work perfectly normally

Comment: Obviously the `FormatCondition.Borders` does not use the right `xlBordersIndex` enumeration. Instead it uses `xlTop`, `xlLeft`, `xlBottom`, `xlRight`. But according to the documentation that's wrong and must be a bug.

Comment: Agreed. This presumably explains the `b1.ThemeColor` issue too. Any idea on `cf1.Interior.InvertIfNegative`?

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke sorry no Idea for that one.

Comment: Nah, the `b1.ThemeColor` issue is still an issue. Only occurs on some of the borders, not all of them. Seems to be where there is a line in the format. And I just found a note on that: `Attempting to access a theme color for an object whose color is not currently themed will result in an invalid request run-time error` Now I just need to figure out how to tell if a color is themed... :(   Thanks for all your help, that was great

Comment: I note that (at least on my computer) `xlBottom` is -4107, yet `cf1.Borders.item(xlBottom)` seems to get the same border as `cf1.Borders.item(4)`. What's that about?

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke Actually I figured out the same. But I think there must be two kind of indices. The ones that count the items from 1 … n and the ones that use the values from the enumeration `xlBottom` or `xlEdgeBottom`. Otherwise I cannot explain why `xlBottom` (and the others) work as intended.